# Xiaomi Mi Max lock with screen with picture of phone with usb cable and "pcsuite.mi.com" url, regular reboot, no pcsuite connect

Tags: lock-screens, boot-loop, reboot, xiaomi

How can i bypass the screen with "pcsuite.mi.com" url and picture of phone with usb cable?

Below is the image of boot lock screen when Mi Max is not connected to PC:
[image: boot lock screen when Mi Max is not connected to PC]
<sup>Click to enlarge the image</sup>

I was using my phone (Xiaomi Mi Max Dual SIM with 4GB RAM + 128GB ROM) and i got that screen. None of the buttons seams to dismiss the screen. Reboot always go to the same screen (boot loop). Can't use the phone (no calls, alarms, etc).

Below is the screen, when is connected to PC (the cable changes position in the image).

[image: Mi lock screen when connected to pc]
<sup>Click to enlarge the image</sup>

I download the pcsuite, mi flash and mi unlock on my pc but can't connect to device (even when i run the apps as administrator).

Below is Mi Pc Suite screen:
[image: mi suite no device detected]
<sup>Click to enlarge the image</sup>

Below is the Mi Unlock screen (no device connected):
[image: Mi Unlock no device detected]
<sup>Click to enlarge the image</sup>

ps specs are:

- Dell OptiPlex 7020 CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz
- Dell Motherboard 0F5C5X with Intel PCH Q87
- Microsoft Windows 7 Professional (64-bit) Service Pack 1 (build 7601)

Have issues with "SM Bus Controller driver" that are now solved. I read in the foruns that Max is not yet supported by pc suite. pcsuite can't connect detect phone, but adb driver installed with success.

Mi Suite and Mi Unlock don't identify the device. Mi Flash detects the device if i boot with volume-down + power (and got a back screen). The flash failed on the initial tries, because the device don't reply to the hello package.

If i boot with power pressed for 8 sec (or more), i got into the phone + pcsuite lock screen and Mi Suite, Flash and Unlock don't detect it.

I try power up with volume up, volume down, volume up+down and no recovery screen (no rabbit or fast boot leters). Still can't use my Mi Max: no calls, no access to apps, nothing :(

The pc suit logs are at https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-J9Wa8DpsEzU0RTV3VMR0ZuRGs

Does the Mi Flash util work without the unlock boot? I already got the sms unlock code, can login into my Mi account inside Mi unlock fine.

**New steps**

Reboot the phone using power + volume up + volume down (EDL mode - back screen)
Connect to PC, install the Qualcomm HS-USB QDLoader 9008 driver, Mi Flash detect the device and i could flash the helium_global_images_V8.2.1.0.MBDMIDL (full flash, delete all).

[image: mi flash success]
<sup>Click to enlarge the image</sup>

I use a normal cable (no deep flash cable). I did the flash but **did not** open the case, remove the battery or short the testing points.

Below is the mi max test points photo (from tutorial on web).
[image: Mi Max test points]
<sup>Click to enlarge the image</sup>

When i reboot the phone (power button for 8 secounds) still get into the same "pcsuite.mi.com" and phone image screen. Mi Pc suite and Mi unlock don't identify my phone in 9008 / EDL mode.

**Last steps**

Phone is working, Can't still unlock. "time is too short" screen below:

[image: time is too short]
<sup>Click to enlarge the image</sup>

Comment: what happens when press and hold power button for 15 seconds? Bootloader is locked, so you cannot go to recovery.

Comment: press and hold power button keeps me on the Mi starting screen. After release, it goes into the back screen and later the  screen with picure of phone with usb cable and the "pcsuite.mi.com" url. The picture change if the cable is connected to pc or not.

Comment: Do you have tried to unlock boot loader? Or, what may be the cause?

Comment: To put it another way, what were you doing when it first happened?

Comment: I got my Mi max an month ago. I was using Whatsapp and vlc to see videos.

Comment: @RahulGopi I only try to unlock the boot loader now. I'm waiting for the code by sms.

Comment: It may take sometime to receive SMS(I have got after 2 days). They're telling it will take about 3-21 days. Ref: http://xiaomiadvices.com/unlock-bootloader-xiaomi-mi-flash-tool/

Comment: yep. It's great if i get the code in 3 days or less.

Comment: I don't think you can unlock the bootloader without booting into the OS, logging into MI account and flagging it for unlock permission on this device. That's how modern MI devices counter thefts, after all.

Comment: What you CAN try right now (and possibly the only way out at this point) is the EDL (Qualcomm 9008) mode. Please verify: hold VOL+ and VOL-, and press POWER to boot; the phone should vibrate once with the screen still black. Connect the phone to the PC, and if proper drivers have already been installed, you should see an entry under "COM port" or "Ports" that says something containing "9008". If it successfully connects in this mode, there is still a chance to recover; more to follow after your verification.

Comment: Have you tried Zcx twrp for mi max hydrogen ? You can try these instructions from: http://en.miui.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=365918&highlight=TWRP , from the looks of it it works on both locked and unlocked bootloaders

Comment: I'm waiting xiaomi reply if there is any close Belgium official Xiaomi resaler/shop/repair center. Already downloaded the helium global images V8.2.1.0 MBDMIDL and read the Max hydrogen, but since I buy my Xiaomi Mi Max from VolumeRate.com at 30/04/2017, and got in my hands at 8/06/2017, it got 1 month and i hope to have some sort of waranty.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat i read it, but didn't open my phone yet (to remove the batery and do the sort in the test points.

Comment: @RahulGopi Yes, i try to unlock the boot loader

Comment: Do i need a special usb cable for EDL like https://www.fonefunshop.com/edl-deep-flash-qualcomm-9008-2-in-1-cable-for-z3x-octopus.html ?

Comment: You might need one, but you can DIY one from existing USB cables. Guides should be aplenty around the web. @xavier_fakerat pointed you in the right direction - the link he offered you basically taught you how to enter EDL mode and recover from there.

Comment: I now have the phone working, already re-install all, update the image and i'm waiting 72h to unclok the device (I'm afraid of getting this error again). It's related to an hardware issue in the volume up button. I'll post all the information and steps soon.

Answer (score 1):

Try booting with both volume up and down pressed, and only then connect to the pc, if the PC recognizes it as Qualcomm 9008 (COM*somenumber*) you are set, open MiFlash and flash the latest ROM
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Mi Flash detect the device and i could flash the helium_global_images_V8.2.1.0.MBDMIDL or any other image, but still go back to the same lock screen

Comment: Ok then try to flash a china dev and after that report back please.

Answer (score 0):

First of all connect it to PC via adb and backup your required data. Follow this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/179288/225285) for it

Try this command `adb reboot bootloader` or `adb reboot recovery`
If any of the command works then you can flash stock image directly from bootloader using fastboot or from recovery.

[adb and fastboot commands for xiomi](http://en.miui.com/thread-24219-1-1.html)

If above mentioned method does not work then try this

As you have got unlock code, you can unlock bootloader now. (Typically after 1 week of requesting you can successfully do it).I guess you would be able to do it now so follow this method now.

After unlocking you can do either one of the following tasks

1. Flash a custom recovery (prefer TWRP) and then custom ROM
2. Download stock image for the device and flash it [link](http://en.miui.com/download-302.html)

Comment: I can't unlock, since after working, i need to associate my mi account with the device and wait at least 74h

Comment: try flashing the stock image via adb or any other flash tool made by xiomi or wait 74 hr

Comment: @PedroPolonia as you are unable to flash stock rom so you should flash a custom recovery and custom rom